# Matrix equation equal to zero solution

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a matrix equation of the form:

$$AXA'=0$$

Where $A$ is of dimension $(p \times n)$ and $X$ is of dimension  $(n \times n)$ with $n>p$. I know $A$, I do not know $X$. Can there be any non-trivial solutions to this equation for $X$? And if so, when do they exist and how can I find them?

Edit: There are definitely situations in which non-trivial solutions exist. For example, if:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

A possible solution for $X$ exists as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Presumably you mean $n > p$, as your example would indicate

Comment: It would suffice to construct an X whose rows are orthogonal to the kernel of A'. So if you know A, then you can find the kernel of A', then you can construct such an X.

Comment: Apologies you are right n>p

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts on the problem:

I will stick to the case where $X$ is symmetric.

First, the case where $A$ is of dimension $n \times n$, and $A$ is invertible. In this case, we have [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), which states that $AXA'$ will necessarily have the same "inertia" as $X$. For instance, if $X$ is positive or negative semidefinite, then $AXA'$ will also be positive or negative semidefinite of the same rank.

With that, break this square matrix $A$ into blocks
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_1\\A_2}
$$
where $A_1$ is $p \times n$. We then find that we can write
$$
AXA' = \pmatrix{A_1XA_1' & A_1 XA_2'\\ A_2XA_1' & A_2XA_2'}.
$$
With that, we can now address the case where $A$ is $p \times n$ of full row-rank: we see that if $A_1$ is such a matrix, then it must be that $A_1XA_1'$ is a $p \times p$ submatrix of some matrix whose signature is equal to that of $X$.

With that, the question can be reframed as follows: if $X$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of the form
$$
X = \pmatrix{0 & B\\B^T & C},
$$
then what can its signature be? If $C$ is invertible, then with the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) we find that $X$ is congruent to the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{-BC^{-1}B^T & 0\\0 & C}.
$$
In other words, if $X$ is invertible, then $X$ can have positive signature at most $n-p$.

For the case where $A$ does not have full row-rank, we can use a rank-factorization $A = FG$ to reduce to the case where $A$ has fewer rows but full rank (i.e. we can replace $A$ with $G$).